# Add 2 weeks to date (ending at midnight)

Tags: php, datetime

I have `$end = date('Y.m.d', strtotime("+2 weeks"));`
Log is currently exactly +2 weeks from triggering, but how I can make it end at midnight ?

For example: user triggers log at 1.32pm, it ends after 2 weeks at 23:59:59 ?

Time is stored in unixtime format in database

Comment: After 2 weeks in midnight (11:59:59PM)

Comment: maybe: `$end = date('Y.m.d', strtotime("+2 weeks")) . ' 23:59:59';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$end = date('Y.m.d 23:59:59', strtotime("+2 weeks"));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
echo $end = date('r', strtotime("+2 weeks +1 day midnight -1 sec"));
//  Mon, 01 Aug 2016 23:59:59 +0000
```